# AWK: Output CSV with Quotes and Removed Segments for Mechanical Turk

Tags: csv, awk, mechanicalturk

I need to process a lot of Mechanical Turk HITS fast, so I'm trying to write an AWK command/script.

I need it to do three things:

1. Grab and Print Specific Columns
2. Remove some text from certain fields.
3. Output quoted fields.

I want to take my input:

```
"1","2","Input.image_url","Answer.main"
"1","2","http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg","text"
```

And get out:

```
"image_url","main"
"http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg","text"
```

So far I have

```
awk -F'","|^"|"$' '{sub("^\"","")} {print $3 ", "$4}' test.csv > output.csv
```

Which prints:

```
Input.image_url, Answer.main
http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg, text
```

How would I alter this?

Thanks for the look, I really appreciate it. I'm terribly new at AWK.

EDIT: This snippet works for the sample I provided, but unfortunately something is wrong. I figured I could simplify the input/output to make the job easier, but it seems I've skipped over something. So I will fill in the details...

When I use:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/"[[:alpha:]]+\./,"\""); print $28, $31}' test.csv > output.csv
```

For:

```
"HITId","HITTypeId","Title","Description","Keywords","Reward","CreationTime","MaxAssignments","RequesterAnnotation","AssignmentDurationInSeconds","AutoApprovalDelayInSeconds","Expiration","NumberOfSimilarHITs","LifetimeInSeconds","AssignmentId","WorkerId","AssignmentStatus","AcceptTime","SubmitTime","AutoApprovalTime","ApprovalTime","RejectionTime","RequesterFeedback","WorkTimeInSeconds","LifetimeApprovalRate","Last30DaysApprovalRate","Last7DaysApprovalRate","Input.image_url","Input.main_text","Answer.SEND","Answer.SUBJECT","Answer.main","Approve","Reject"
"373L46LKP7703E3YWZRRTZTZNUJJKX","3H9KHFULG43TZRE1KD4ITGVT4OWCEU","Transcribe the text contained in the image","Transcribe the text contained in the image","transcribe, image, text","$0.01","Mon Aug 25 20:47:26 GMT 2014","1","BatchId:1651513;","900","60","Mon Sep 01 20:47:26 GMT 2014","","","33IZTU6J812191JP8EKV0EN8HD7XS2","A1GOJEDZM2CQTN","Submitted","Mon Aug 25 20:48:15 GMT 2014","Mon Aug 25 20:48:26 GMT 2014","Mon Aug 25 13:49:26 PDT 2014","","","","11","100% (3/3)","100% (3/3)","0% (0/0)","http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg","hippy hay","","","text"
```

It prints:

```
"image_url","main"
"100% (3/3)",""
```

But I need:

```
"image_url","main"
"http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg","text"
```

The first row works great but for some reason it's returning another column in the second row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data always has same number of fields and two lines:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{sub(/[^.]*\./,"\"",$28);split($29,a,"[._]");print $28,"\""a[2]"\""} NR==2 {print $30,$NF}' OFS=, file
"image_url","main"
"http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg","text"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't state in your question how to identify which text to remove from the fields so this may or may not be what you want:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {gsub(/"[[:alpha:]]+\./,"\""); print $3, $4}' file
"image_url","main"
"http://i.imgur.com/rGJA3YU.jpg","text"
```

Comment: That worked great for the code I provided, unfortunately it doesn't work for my real application (I edited with an explanation) Sorry to have mucked this up, but could you take another crack at this? Thanks again!